# my app is working in 5.1.1 version but not working in lower versions

Tags: android, performance

I did some changes in `Gradle` and `Android Manifest` files but there is no luck. Unfortunately the application doesn't run below `Android 5.1.1` displaying

> unfortunately application stopped

Error. See below for my `Gradle` file code and `AndroidManifest.xml` code:

**Gradle:**

```
    android 
    {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.1"
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
        exclude 'META-INF/services/'
    }


    lintOptions {
        disable "ResourceType"
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "ecubed.co.in"
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 15
        versionCode 22
        versionName "3.6.10"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.1'
    compile 'org.apache.poi:poi:3.15-beta2'
    compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.11.0'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3.6'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.3.3'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.3.6'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.1.1'
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.5@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.2.1'
    compile('io.fabric.sdk.android:fabric:1.3.10@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
}
```

**Android Manifest**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="ecubed.co.in">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CONTROL_LOCATION_UPDATES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.network"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"
    android:required="false"/>
<permission
    android:name="ecubed.co.in.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="ecubed.co.in.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:name=".Helpers.MyApplication"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/MyTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/MyTheme1"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.UserPage"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.Crown_Report"
        android:exported="true"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

            <data
                android:host="*"
                android:mimeType="application/*"
                android:pathPattern=".*.xls"
                android:scheme="content" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.SignUp"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.UserDetails"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.Trade"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.Gift_Report"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.Rest_List"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.Waiters_list"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.Coins_Collection"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
    <receiver
        android:name=".Helpers.ConnectivityReceiver"
        android:enabled="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
            <category android:name="ecubed.co.in" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <meta-data
        android:name="io.fabric.ApiKey"
        android:value="e617fb6fd35f34e52bd7ca3f4a58f4d535d58d1e" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
</application>
```

Please can you help me with this error?
Thanks.

Comment: every crash gives a stacktrace which helps to find a problem. Show us the stacktrace

Comment: Maybe you should give a shot for AppCompat.